# Is it possible to play Magicka in LAN?

Tags: magicka

Me and some friends have bought Magicka on Steam and we would like to have a session in a LAN party, without direct internet connection. Is it possible with some tricks?

**Update**: I am able to see my friend game in LAN filter but every time I try to connect the game told me authentication failed.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? "[You start the game like normal, and then the ones who join use the LAN filter.](https://paradox.zendesk.com/entries/437121-Magicka-Where-is-the-LAN-co-op-option)"

Comment: @Batophobia LAN filter works but we get always a problem of authentication

Comment: IS the network secure?

Comment: @YoungGuilo Sorry, I don't know what do you mean.

Comment: Is your internet secure?

Comment: @YoungGuilo I don't know what you mean either. If they can see each other, it's not a wifi security problem, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @Drake Are you online when you try to play, or is the Internet connection removed? It sounds like there may be a central server that still needs to be contacted to validate your game even when just playing LAN.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No we are not online, we have steam in offline mode and no connection with outside

Comment: @Drake That is probably why authentication is failing. You probably can't play LAN without authenticating… but as I'm unfamiliar with the game I can't confirm that's the problem, only give an informed guess.

Comment: Are both your Steam clients in offline mode? You and your friends will need to have Steam in offline mode before trying to play Magicka on LAN (i.e., in offline mode)

Comment: @Bora Yes both Steam clients are in offline mode

Comment: Can anybody confirm if it is possible (or not) to play Magicka in a LAN without steam?

Answer (score 1):

Most games that use Steam as DRM have been programmed to require authentication only once or once per update. Do you get the same message when trying to play a single-player game?

Have you tried the following procedure?

```
   1. Install magicka on all target computers. 
   2. For each of these computers; 
     a. Connect it to the internet
     b. Start a game.
   3. Repeat step (2) without being connected to the internet.
```

The above method should function provided that the game is not coded to authenticate with each game connection attempt. If it is, you may have to circumvent the authentication procedure through directly modifying the game's code.

This may become necessary to get the netplay features of the game working in a future where the authentication server may become unavailable.

Comment: Also, each PC has to have a copy of the game installed. If you try and install the same registered game on 3 PCs, for example... Won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to disable VAC, as it might be the cause of this.

You can find it in the Host game menu(It might not have been available before, but it is now)

Answer (score -3):

If you host a server, no port-forwarding required, then you find out your IPv4 adress by opening the windows command prompt (Windows XP: Start, All Programs, Accessories, Command Prompt) (Windows Vista/7 Start, Type in "cmd" and click on the result) and typing in 'ipconfig'. Somewhere in the list it will say IPv4 adress..............

Start the server and tell everyone in the network to connect to your IPv4 adress

Comment: They have no trouble finding each other, so IP connections have already been made and instructions on how to connect will not help.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And what if that just comes from the game server? (Which also decided based on your shared IP that you are in the LAN)
I have seen this method help for other games.