# Is it possible to host Magicka in a LAN without steam?

Tags: steam, hosting, magicka

I want to play Magicka in a LAN without steam, is it possible?

I am hosting the game in one pc, but the other simply cannot see the game, or connect directly with the ip address.

According to the comments [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129768/is-it-possible-to-play-magicka-in-lan) is because the players have to be registered in steam, can somebody confirm this?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Are all the players in the same Network?

Comment: Yes, and firewalls are down in both computers... I tried with two different routers as well

Comment: We also played Magicka with 4 Players on LAN, but with Steam. I heard you could use Tunngle to create LAN Networks. http://www.tunngle.net/de

Comment: @baumi, that is interesting, but, as a vpn, it would still require connection to the Internet. Tunngle just simmulates a LAN which I already have, the question is if already having a LAN, can I play the game without steam (or without internet connection).

Comment: The most easy way would be steam, because it would create a dedicated server automatically. But just so i know, did you connect with the router ip or the computer ip? I had the same problem on garrys mod when i was port forwarding, everyone could join, but not the ones in my network (That was because they were joining on the router ip).

Comment: I just don't want to use steam, that is what I am asking if it is possible. Have you set this game without steam? I did put the IP of the machine

Comment: We played it through steam, and at this point i think its only possible with 3rd party programms like hamachi and tunngle, this might be your only option. but im gonna try this later and tell you if i got it to work without the help of other programmes.